# How can I make an array of method pointers?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I want to create an array of pointers to methods, so I can quickly select a method to call, based on a integer. But I am struggling a little with the syntax.

What I have now is this:

```
class Foo {
     private:
        void method1();
        void method2();
        void method3();

        void(Foo::*display_functions[3])() = {
            Foo::method1,
            Foo::method2,
            Foo::method3
        };
};
```

But I get the following error message:

```
[bf@localhost method]$ make test
g++     test.cpp   -o test
test.cpp:11:9: error: cannot convert ‘Foo::method1’ from type ‘void (Foo::)()’ to type ‘void (Foo::*)()’
   11 |         };
      |         ^
test.cpp:11:9: error: cannot convert ‘Foo::method2’ from type ‘void (Foo::)()’ to type ‘void (Foo::*)()’
test.cpp:11:9: error: cannot convert ‘Foo::method3’ from type ‘void (Foo::)()’ to type ‘void (Foo::*)()’
make: *** [<builtin>: test] Error 1
```

Comment: You could create a `std::vector<std::function<...>>`.

Comment: How about a member function taking that integer as parameter and calling the appropriate function in a `switch` / `case`? Much less fragile.

Comment: Did you try `&Foo::method1, &Foo::method2, &Foo::method3`?

Comment: To get a pointer to a member function you must *always* use the pointer-to operator `&`.

Comment: It's often really hard to understand C declarations, if you use the standard containers like std::array and std::function instead of the C style function pointers it is much easier to debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can, you just need to take the address of them:

```
        void(Foo::*display_functions[3])() = {
            &Foo::method1,
            &Foo::method2,
            &Foo::method3
        };
```

... however, it's likely better if you have `virtual` methods for an interface or a simple method that calls them all for a multi-method pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typedef` for the type of pointer to your methods, and then store your methods in a [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) holding that type:

```
class Foo {
private:
    void method1() {};
    void method2() {};
    void method3() {};

    typedef void (Foo::* FooMemFn)();

    std::array<FooMemFn,3> display_functions = {
        &Foo::method1,
        &Foo::method2,
        &Foo::method3
    };
};
```

Instead of `typedef` you can also use a `using` statement:

```
using FooMemFn = void (Foo::*)();
```

Note that you must use `operator&` with a class method to obtain a pointer-to-method.

A side note: consider to make `display_functions` static if it will not change between various class instances.

Comment: Not just `static`. That array can even be `constexpr` in C++20. In particular, gcc can optimise the call if the index is a constexpr: https://godbolt.org/z/44o47rqqd